# How do you feed your prisoners?

Tags: rimworld

I got attacked by and captured two individuals. These are now being stored in a room for prisoners but I can't seem to work out how to ensure they get fed. As you can see from the below, one of them has now seemingly died?

[image]

I have ensured that the "Gets food" check is enabled, and I have plenty of food resources to go around but these prisoners don't seem to be getting fed.

How do you feed your prisoners?

Comment: As I can see from the options, this game surely is fun...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to feed your prisoners, you have to have a colonist assigned to the Warden task.

[image: Overview of Colonist Tasks]

Once you have someone tasked with being a Warden, they will automatically take care of the prisoner; whether they're feeding them, or executing them.

Comment: FWIW, if you don't have a warden but a prisoner, there should be a warning for this in the message area, top right.

Answer (score 6):

In order to make sure your prisoners are fed, you must have at least one colonist with the **Warden** job active in the Overview.

Answer (score 6):

As per current version 0.15+ you have at least 3 options for [feeding prisoners](http://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Prisoner#Gets_food). You can:

- **Have a [Nutrient paste dispenser](http://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Nutrient_paste_dispenser) in your prison** (prisoners feed themselves)
- Have a [warden](http://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Menus#Warden) assigned (warden feeds each prisoner individually - brings food)
- Just have a stock of food on the ground in your prison (prisoners feed themselves)

The nutrient pase dispenser is the best way. Just place it in your prison wall, have the hopper outside of the prison so the colonist doesn't need to go in. If you have a lot of prisoners you can even have 2-3 hoppers. Now you need to turn off the "Gets food" option in your prisoners tab (so warden doesn't bring them food).

[image]

I also recommend setting the dispenser's food for something you have in excess (so you are not wasting some excellent meat on your prisoners.)

[image: nutrient dispenser in prison]

*OT: I also have a stock of tribal wear in my prison because I strip them from all of their nice clothes.*

Comment: Note: Food left on the ground in prison areas is restricted to prisoners only. Your colonists will not be able to interact with it so make sure they are not using the prison area as a passing zone when they are hauling.

Comment: How do you feed the hopper though? It says "cannot feed hopper: reserved for prisoners."

Comment: And where is the "Prisoners" tab to switch of "Get's food?"