# How to feed hopper when owned by prisoners?

Tags: rimworld

How do you feed a hopper in a prisoner area, for example for a nutrient paste dispenser? When I try to direct a colonist to feed one, I see the error "Cannot feed hopper: reserved for prisoners."

Comment: This is almost certainly because you built the hopper inside the prisoner zone. You'll get the same message if you make an item zone inside the prisoner area and dump clothes etc there.

Answer (score 1):

Hoppers are used by Nutrient Paste Dispensers to provide food for turning into paste. The hopper needs to be next to the dispenser to feed it, but hoppers can't be in prisoner areas because colonists won't fill them.

But... dispensers are pretty big, so you can construct one *into the wall of your prison*, such that the *front* is accessible by prisoners, and the *rear* is in a non-prisoner area, into which you can put your hoppers. Colonists will happily fill those hoppers as they're not part of a prison.

Below image taken from [this answer to a similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/291899/77065) (which is a good read if you're looking at mass prisoner feeding solutions.)

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's how I built mine too but it wouldn't let me fill it. Not sure why my question got voted down. Would be courteous for folks to leave a comment when voting down as to the reason.

Comment: @geoidesic While I'm not the downvoter, one thing that might help people diagnose your problem is including more information, or especially a screen shot.